# Does 'this' always point on the current scope in a template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Is it always safe** to use `this` inside a template to get a reference on the current scope?

```
<span ng-click="log(this)">
    Is my onclick parameter always the current controllers scope?
</span>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burninggramma/LH9hc/12/) to show what I mean.

Searched around as well, but couldn't find any point on this in the docs. It seems to work, however I don't want to depend on an undocumented feature. If you can, **please link the proper doc** for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `log(this)` is evaluated against the scope, and `scope` object has a `this` property in it as well which points to its own reference. So it will evaluate `this` against the scope will yield the scope itself. For example you could also pass `$parent` and you will see it will point to the parent scope since the argument in the expression gets evaluated against the current scope will yield `scope['$parent']` similarly it happens to scope['this'] too. *Using `ng-click="method(this)"` in angular context completely different from doing `onclick="somefunc(this)"` on a DOM element. Angular is able to expand it only because it has a property with the name `this` attached to the scope object.*

Another thing is you do not need to pass `this` even otherwise the method is run by evaluating against the scope object, so referring to this will yield the scope itself. i.e you could as well do `ng-click="log()"` and in the log method you can refer to `this` as the current scope where the element is bound to. For instance if you were using `controllerAs` syntax and you are calling:

```
<div ng-controller="MyOtherCtrl as vm">
    <span ng-click="vm.log(this)">Click on me, if background gets teal, then this points on the child controllers scope</span>
</div>
```

Now `this` will not be the controller instance (which is what you would generally expect it to be), instead it will just be the `scope` object itself as it evaluates the expression as `scope.vm.log(scope.this)`

It would always be safer to use `$scope` in the context of the controller, unless you specifically want to refer to some child scope created on the view due to some directive(by some ng-repeat, ng-if etc..) wrapping that particular context. Also remember properties get prototypically inherited (except for isolated scoped directive) in the child scopes.

And there are no links documented or anything as far as i know, but  source code itself is the official record. Angular uses `$parse` to expand the expressions and if you see the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c90ad96808be350526516626205c3a7d1da79024/src/ng/parse.js#L699) you can see that angular invokes the expressions with `function.apply` with the context.

Comment: Ty, I guess I forgot to look inside simple properties of the $scope object. However my use case is a bit different, that is why I need the `this` param. As angular defines private vars (which can officially change in the next version) w/ $$ notation do you think its safe to assume, it won't happen w/ $scope.this?

Comment: @burninggramma yes exactly if you read my last paragraph. You can see that i have mentioned it. You can easily use `this` directly in the log method as well, you do not necessarily need to pass it around.

Comment: @burninggramma See this http://jsfiddle.net/f2juus4a/ using `method(this)` in angular context completely different from doing `onclick="somefunc(this)"` on a DOM element.

Comment: ahh ofc, every property (the functions as well) are properties of the `$scope` object, then its just pure JS that `this` points on the current `$scope` inside the service function as well.

Comment: Exactly. That is the point, but if you do `this` in the view it is not same as doing it on a DOM element, angular expands it diffently.  So in javascript `this` depends upon the calling context (unless it is a bound function created using angular.bind, function.bind etc..). But do not get confused with that and using `this` inside the view in angular.

Comment: Ye, that part is not my problem. [: anyway thx for the answer, marking it.

Comment: @burninggramma You are welcome, hope i was able to clarify enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the $scope of the controller directive.

For eg:

```
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
   <span ng-click="log(this)">
      Is my onclick parameter always the current controllers scope?
   </span>
</div>
```

So, `this` is referring to the `myCntrl`'s $scope.